# MAPPING of flat structure using CORRESPONDING without LOOP

Tags: abap

I'm on ABAP 7.4 SP13.

I would like to use "Option 2" in the code below, but how can I do this deep mapping? The goal here is to have a clean, simple, easy-to-read mapping, avoiding the loop.

```
TYPES:
    BEGIN OF ty_s_audit,                   
      CreatedBy           TYPE ernam,
      LastChangedBy       TYPE aenam,
    END OF ty_s_audit,
    BEGIN OF ty_s_equipment,
      EquipmentId           TYPE equi-equnr,
      Audit                 TYPE ty_s_audit BOXED,
    END OF ty_s_equipment,
    ty_t_equipment TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_s_equipment WITH KEY PRIMARY_KEY COMPONENTS EquipmentId.

DATA: lt_equipments TYPE ty_t_equipment.

  SELECT equnr, ernam, aenam FROM equi INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_equi).

  "Option 1:
  LOOP AT lt_equi ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_equi>).
    APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_equipments ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_equipment>).

    <ls_equipment> = CORRESPONDING #( <ls_equi> MAPPING EquipmentId = EQUNR ).

    <ls_equipment>-Audit = CORRESPONDING #( <ls_equi> MAPPING CreatedBy     = ERNAM
                                                              LastChangedBy = AENAM ).
  ENDLOOP.

  "Option 2:
  lt_equipments = CORRESPONDING #( lt_equi MAPPING EquipmentId          = EQUNR
                                                   “Audit-CreatedBy     = ERNAM
                                                   “Audit-LastChangedBy = AENAM ).
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, what about the following solution?

```
lt_equipments = VALUE #( FOR i IN lt_equi
  (
    equipmentid = i-equnr
    audit-createdby = i-ernam
    audit-lastchangedby = i-aenam
  )
).
```

Or if you really want to use `CORRESPONDING MAPPING` somewhere then for example.

```
lt_equipments = VALUE #( FOR i IN lt_equi
  (
    equipmentid = i-equnr
    audit = CORRESPONDING #( i MAPPING createdby = ernam lastchangedby = aenam )
  )
).
```

Comment: I tried using table_line. It is not working. corresponding #( lt_equi mapping equipmentid = equnr
                                                      ( audit = table_line mapping
                                                           createdby     = ernam
                                                              lastchangedby = aenam ) ).

Comment: Thank you! The first one is perfect for this use case!